# How can I select a specific button with an id?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScrip and I would like to know how I can select a submit button with a specific ID.
I tried to use "getElementById" but the console prints "null".

HTML CODE

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Welcone to the booking site </h1>
  <h4> Please, choose a destination </h4>
</body>
<form name="myTravelForm">
  <select name="destination">
    <option value="Antarctica" selected>Antarctica</option>
    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Add this destination" id="banana" />
</form>

<div id="travelerInfo"></div>

</html>
```

JavaScript code

```js
var x;
x = document.getElementById("banana")
console.log(x)
```

Comment: The </body> should be closed before </html> and the javascript code is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is relatively correct you need to put all html within body tags. Also your script gets triggered before the document is finished with loading fully. 
You should put your script before closing `body`, so it gets triggered after all DOM elements are loaded.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Welcone to the booking site </h1>
        <h4> Please, choose a destination </h4>

        <form name="myTravelForm">
            <select name="destination">
                <option value="Antarctica" selected>Antarctica</option>
                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Add this destination" id="banana"/>
        </form>

        <div id="travelerInfo"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is also solution to leave script.js within head tag, but wrap the code within a function and call it within onload placed within body tag as an attribute.

In script.js:

```
function findID(){
  var x;

  x = document.getElementById("banana")
   console.log(x)

 }
```

Within body tag:

```
<body onload="findID();">
```

Or you can leave your `script.js` within `<head>` tag but wrap the code within with an `window.onload` or `document.onload`. This might be the most elegant solution.

```
window.onload = function(e){
  var x;

  x = document.getElementById("banana")
   console.log(x)

 }
```

Comment: Do you mean adding "<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>" to the body and not to the head?

Comment: @Prova12, yes, it should be placed within body tag, but right before closing body tag. I have edited my answer, so you can check example. Also, there are few other approaches, I have also added within an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's working properly, write `html` code inside `body`

See in code below:

```js
var x;
x = document.getElementById("banana")
console.log(x)
console.log(x.value)
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Welcone to the booking site </h1>
  <h4> Please, choose a destination </h4>

  <form name="myTravelForm">
    <select name="destination">
      <option value="Antarctica" selected>Antarctica</option>
      <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Add this destination" id="banana" />
  </form>

  <div id="travelerInfo"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your js is executing before the elements are loaded. Try with an HTML like this:

```
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Welcone to the  booking site </h1>
        <h4> Please, choose a destination </h4>
    </body>
        <form name="myTravelForm">
    <select name="destination">
        <option value="Antarctica" selected>Antarctica</option>
        <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
    </select>
        <input type="button" value="Add this destination" id="banana"/>
        </form>

        <div id="travelerInfo"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track.
You should wait until all elements are loaded. Just add in

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   var x;
   x = document.getElementById("banana")
   console.log(x)
   console.log(x.value)
});
```

Or if you are using JQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```